# Line integral $\int_C y \ \rm ds$, $C$ given by $y=2\sqrt x$ from $x=3$ to $x=24$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could I have some help with this problem?

Calculate the following line integral: $\int_C y \ ds$

along the curve $C$ given by $y=2\sqrt x$ from $x=3$ to $x=24$.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: How do I start? Do I need o parametrise the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first parameterize the curve, say by $\vec r(t)=\langle x(t),y(t)\rangle$ from $t=a$ to $t=b.$ An easy parameterization and values of $a,b$ should immediately suggest themselves.

Then use $$\int_C f\,ds=\int_a^b f\left(\vec r(t)\right)\left|\vec r'(t)\right|\,dt.$$

Comment: Sorry but I'm still unsure on how to do it. Would you be able to show me how you would do this example?

Comment: Well, what parameterization did you come up with? Note that you already have $y$ as a one-to-one function of $x,$ so that should make things easier.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right but would it be something likee r(t)=(t,2sqrt(t))

Comment: Yes, indeed! And it should run from $t=?$ to $t=?$

Comment: Would it be from t=3 to t=24

Comment: Precisely that! Now you need to find $$\left|\vec r'(t)\right|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}.$$

Comment: |r'|=sqrt(1+(1/t))

Comment: then integrating 2sqrt(x).|r'(t)| between 3 and 24 got the answer i was looking for. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You're very welcome!